# Split csv file into SINGLE COLUMN text files

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file with stock data with 7 columns, that is 7 comma- separated values per row. There are thousands of rows, and I want to read this file and write the columns in their entirety to individual text files. 
This should not be to difficult but I can find no one doing this kind of operation ?
To make it perfectly clear. I have 1 .csv file with 7 comma- separated values. I want to write these to 7 text files based on column.
Anybody who have done this and can assist ? Much obliged.

Comment: What's stopping you from writing the code? Or you need assistance for installing an IDE or learning a language?

Comment: We're kind of like fire fighters here. We run in and help with the burning building (code that doesn't work), but we don't help light it on fire. You can find examples for using the `csv` module to read a csv. That reader returns rows and you can have open files for each column and write the rows. Good luck. Post code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pseudocode**:

```
with open CSV, open file column 1,  open file column 2, ..., open file column 7:
    fh = [fh1, fh2, ... fh7]
    while CSV readline
       for I, column_data in CSV line:
           fh[I].write(column_data)
```